# Siebel promotion groups

Tags: product, siebel

I would like to know if I can use the promotion group functionality to take one product from a product line that I have used as membership, and another from a product class that I have used also as another membership?

I want this to used it as compatibility rule, I.E., a product from product line A excludes product A from product class A.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, it appears to be possible, since the application GUI in the Product Admin screen allows for the creation of such rules. There is a serious limitation on what it can do, however. The relationship between Products and Product Lines is M:M, but Siebel Compatibility does not evaluate all of these relationships when the compatibility rules run. What happens, in fact, is that the Primary Product Line associated to a given product (set as default by the application for performance reasons) is the only one that ever gets evaluated. I pointed this out to Oracle (see issue #3-4982911601 on support.oracle.com), and they came back saying they would issue an enhancement request, but that will be subject to priority, so who knows when it will be applied.